# how to computer performace of a pro c file

Tags: c, performance, loader

I have come across `.prof` file (at least the extension tell me so) which I think was used to analyze the performance of loaders which are  written in pro c language.

I am writing a new similar loader and I want to analyze the performance of my program.

I have pasted the first few lines of `.prof` file here :

```
%Time Seconds Cumsecs  #Calls   msec/call  Name
  90.8  235.13  235.13       0      0.0000  strlen
   3.2    8.17  243.30       0      0.0000  _read
   1.3    3.33  246.63  897580      0.0037  Search
   1.0    2.56  249.19       0      0.0000  _lseek
   0.6    1.43  250.62       0      0.0000  _kill
   0.5    1.39  252.01       0      0.0000  _write
   0.3    0.83  252.84  864734      0.0010  _doprnt
   0.3    0.75  253.59       0      0.0000  _mcount0
```

I am interested in two points:

- which kind of file is this
- how can i generate such a file in unix environment (command?)

Comment: Either gprof, or a strace output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like an (outdated?) [gprof flat profile](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.16/gprof/Flat-Profile.html#Flat-Profile).

These are generated with gcc by adding `-pg` to the command line options, and running the program.

The profile tells us that the tested code spends a very long time running `strlen()`.

Comment: Maybe the author had the habit of `for (i = 0; i < strlen(cp); i++) { ... } `